# Create polygon shapefile from point shapefile in python

Tags: python-3.x, polygon, qgis

I am a beginner (very little experience) in Python. I am trying to use it with QGIS.

I have a points shapefile (`pt.shp`), and I would like to create a polygon shapefile (`pol.shp`) using Python.
Could anyone suggest code to build a polygon shapefile from the points shapefile?

I have only been able to order the points using `geopandas` with the following code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
shp = 'pt.shp'
gdf_pol = gpd.read_file(shp) # Read shapefile as geodataframe
ordered_gdf = gdf_pol.sort_values('point_id') # Sort by NAME column
print(ordered_gdf)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you have and haven't already researched? You haven't indicated that you've googled how to do this, or looked at any of the existing solutions. For instance, when I googled your question, I immediately found [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/431981/converting-point-shapefile-to-polygon-shapefile-python) which seems to be asking the same thing. So, can you clarify why you need help, and why none of the info existing online was able to help you?

Comment: Hi Davis. thanks for your answer. Actually I have found that post, but the true is that i do not understand it. I just want to connect the points to make a polygon and save it in a shapefile. The post that you have refered uses the buffer tool. Sorry, but i am really new to this...Thanks.